# How to obtain javascript code from a website, that checks my input on a form?

Tags: javascript, html, http, web, firebug

I am writing a simple program that obtains some user input, then puts this input into database, then another program reads that data and tries to send it to another site. The problem is, that this site has a form validation, so i need my user input to be exactly the same as a validation on target site.

So now, my question is, how can i easily check what javascript code is triggered on this site, when i try to send invalid data?

Comment: Have you tried working with the designers of that other site to sync up validation logic?

Comment: It's a banking site. And i live in a country that "noone knows nothing" :-(

Comment: @ojek unless u know exactly what format the receiving website expects, u will be left with trial and error. And you need the banking website's server validations not client validation as I assuming ur gonna POST to their system.

Comment: @Sajjan Sarkar: Naw, i asked for javascript, since i need that validation.

Comment: @ojek i have to say your a requirement is a strange and somewhat suspicious one. I cannot think of one reason why you would want to "simulate" a client level submit to a "banking site" and not a server POST. Please post more info about why you cannot elaborate on why you are not POST-ing.

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome, using the web developer tools, I would see if the input element has an ID or a class that is used to get that element using javascript.

Then in the sources tab, I would press ctrl+f (cmd+f for mac) and then sear for the input's class or ID, this will highlight any JS or CSS line that contains that specific class or ID. That way you could find any bindings done for the input such as on key press or at least some kind of validation once the form is submitted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got something like this: `cib.addOnLoad( function() { dojo.byId('cibGlobals').global.invalidElements.push('p_trn_bnf_name[0]'); });});`. And i have no idea what now... Dojo is some kind of js tool, but what next? :-/

Answer (score 0):

As Sajjan said, I assume you're going to be posting that data to their servers, as it would make NO sense to actually go through their client interface to send them data.

In that case, all you can do is send test data to their servers to see how the server reacts. Send empty strings, NULL values, strings with hundreds of characters, strings with a whole bunch of strange characters, etc. Work on breaking their system as best as you can. Hopefully, this can help you give you some sort of idea of what their validation logic is like.

Comment: That's not how things work. ;)

Comment: @ojek how strange that you think that that's not how it works.. hmmmmm.....